# When I try to convert String to Date it return today's date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Here is the String example I am trying to convert to Date
`

```js
let sdate = "2008-08-17T07:24:03.000Z";
let xdate = Date(sdate);
console.log(xdate);
```

`

Am I using Date wrong?
How should I convert dateformat of any String to Date?
Why does Date return today's date instead of given date?

Comment: Does this answer your question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript) ?

Comment: When called as a function, Date returns a string for the current date and time, ignoring any arguments passed to it. When called as a constructor, it creates a new Date object based on the arguments passed (if any). If you want to parse a string to a date, then call it as a constructor with *new*: `new Date(sdate)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use new Date constructor.

```js
let sdate = "2008-08-17T07:24:03.000Z";
let xdate = new Date(sdate);
console.log(xdate);
```